# Export Function does not return data when Sequelize.findAll on another file

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, return-value

I get some data from request query & with that requested param send to **MySQL** database. When Request successful then it returns data (**Main controller File**) & on behalf of that data I need to call some other functions that exist on other model class(**Common Method File**). **Common Method File** function also have some database dependency. When I am debugging from **Common Method File** it returns data as per expectation. But it does not return any data from (**Main controller File**). What should I do now?

I also try this to convert async await but it fail.

**Main controller File**

```
    const MenuData = require('../../models/common/MenuData');    
    const MenuModel = require('../../models/menu/menuModel');

    exports.listMenu = function(req, res) {
    let menu_id = 0;

    if(req.query.menuID){
        menu_id=req.query.menuID;
        MenuModel.findOne({
            where:{
                id:menu_id
            }
        }).then(menu=>{
                if(menu){
                    let menu_details =  MenuData.menuDetails(menu.dataValues);
                    if(menu_details){
                        return res.send({status: 200, message: menu_details});
                    }else{
                        return res.send({status: 302, message: "Data Not Found"});
                    }
                }
            }).catch(err =>{
            return res.send('error: '+err);
            });
    }else{
        return res.send('error: '+err);;
    }
};
```

**Common Method File**

```
    const MenuRelationalModel = require('../../models/menu/menuRelationModel');

    exports.menuDetails=(content_data)=>{
     let data = [];
     if(content_data){
        if(content_data.id && content_data.id == 1){
            MenuRelationalModel.findAll({
                where:{
                    menu_id:content_data.id
                }
            }).then(menu_all_data =>{
                if(menu_all_data){
                    menu_all_data.map((menu_item,index)=>{
                        data.push(menu_item.dataValues);
                    })
                    return data;
                }

            }).catch(err =>{
                data.push(err);
                return data;

            });
        }

      }
   }
```

***Coming Output***

```
   {
    "status": 302,
    "message": []
   }
```

***Expected Output***

```
   {
     "status": 200,
     "message": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "menu_id": 1,
            "parent_page_id": 0,
            "page_id": 1,
            "item_title": "Ongoing",
            "item_type": "category",
            "parent_type": "category"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "menu_id": 1,
            "parent_page_id": 0,
            "page_id": 2,
            "item_title": "Completed",
            "item_type": "category",
            "parent_type": "category"
        }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: your menu is found in mysql but the menuDetails seems null here:     let menu_details =  MenuData.menuDetails(menu.dataValues);

Comment: Yeah! but MenuData.menuDetails() console.log returns data on then. Just then function doesnot return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your common method is async, so you've to return a promise.

```
    const MenuRelationalModel = require('../../models/menu/menuRelationModel');

    exports.menuDetails=(content_data)=>{
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           let data = [];
           if(content_data){
              if(content_data.id && content_data.id == 1){
                 MenuRelationalModel.findAll({
                     where:{
                        menu_id:content_data.id
                     }
                 }).then(menu_all_data =>{
                    if(menu_all_data){
                        menu_all_data.map((menu_item,index)=>{
                             data.push(menu_item.dataValues);
                        })
                        resolve(data);
                     }
                 }).catch(err =>{
                      data.push(err);
                      resolve(data);    
                 });
             }
          } else {
              resolve(data);
          }
      })
   }
```

And in you main code

```
if (menu) {
  MenuData.menuDetails(menu.dataValues).then(menu_details => {
    if (menu_details) {
      return res.send({ status: 200, message: menu_details });
    } else {
      return res.send({ status: 302, message: "Data Not Found" });
    }
  });
}
```